# Prove that no integer $w$ exists such that the splitting field of $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1+w$ is that of $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$.

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, field-theory, splitting-field, cyclotomic-fields

For $x^2+x+1$, there exist infinitely many integers $w$ such that the splitting field of $x^2+x+1+w$ is the same field as $x^2+x+1$.
Examples of such integers $w$ are $$6, 60, 546, 4920,\ldots\,.$$ There is a closed form for odd $k$, namely $$w=\frac{3^k+1}{4}-1\,.$$

I can't seem to prove / disprove this for the fact of whether there are infinitely many integers $w$ such that the splitting field of $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1+w$ is the same field as the splitting field $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$.

The same with whether there are infinitely many integers $w$ such that the splitting field of $x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1+w$ is the same field as the splitting field $x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$.

If there is at least one integer $w$ for degrees $4$ or $6$, please post them as a counterexample.

Comment: Are you looking at this modulo some prime or what? I have this suspicion that the [tag:finite-fields] tag is mistakenly included. Because you discuss integers it seems to me that your fields are infinite (because they contain $\Bbb{Q}$, an infinite set, as a subfield). A cool question nevertheless.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen for the nth cyclotomic polynomial defined in field Zn